# Trailing return-type syntax fails with noexcept specifier?

Tags: c++, c++11

This code work as expected:

```
void f() noexcept {}
```

But the following fails with an error in GCC 4.7.2:

```
auto f() -> void noexcept {}

// error: expected initializer before ‘noexcept’
```

Articles I've read haven't said anything about not being able to specify `noexcept` in a training return-type. Is this a bug (and had it been fixed in the newest version of GCC)? Or is this prohibited explicitly by the Standard?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is not the correct syntax. It should be:

```
auto f() noexcept -> void { }
```

Per paragraph 8.4.1/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> `D1` ( *parameter-declaration-clause* ) *cv-qualifier-seq(opt)*
>
> *ref-qualifier(opt)* *exception-specification(opt)* *attribute-specifier-seq(opt)* *trailing-return-type(opt)*
>
> as described in 8.3.5. A function shall be defined only in namespace or class scope.