# Is the new C++ return syntax limited?

Tags: c++, c++11, return

I started a new private project and decided to use more [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)/[14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) this time. So I also started using the new return syntax

```
auto functionName() -> returnType;
```

It works for the most part very well, but now I needed some error handling and could not find out how to re-write stuff like this:

```
virtual const char* what() const noexcept override;
```

with the new syntax. Are there some cases where the new syntax can not be used or am I only not clever enough to find the right order? For me it is important to keep things consistent, so I hope the problem is more on my side.

Comment: for noexcept see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598320/trailing-return-type-syntax-fails-with-noexcept-specifier

Comment: The new return type thing is really a hack to allow the use of decltype() on the function parameters. Since function parameters can only be used in decltype _after_ they have been declared, such a construct cannot be placed in the 'old' spot for the return type - so they moved the return type around. In my opinion, this is helping the compiler writers too much at the cost of making the entire language less usuable for everybody else. At any rate, there is no ideological reason for you to convert entire projects to 'new' syntax; it is not inherently better or more modern.

Comment: I don't know of any reason to use the trailing return type syntax in non-generic code, unless you think it looks nicer. There are some C++11 features like `auto` or brace initialization that are arguably intended to be used "by default" in all "modern" code, but I'm pretty sure trailing return types only exist to support a certain subset of typesafe generic code that wasn't possible to write before.

Comment: @lxrec: I did find it useful in the following case: Suppose I want to declare member functions of some class and register them somewhere at compile-time. To avoid a lot of boiler-plate, probably I will use a macro. However, if a macro begins a function declaration, it must also include the return type, since that appears after the function name. If you use the trailing return type syntax, then that is alleviated. The macro can do something with `&my_type::NAME` and then also declare `auto NAME ` and leave the user to specify the signature and, if they want, the definition.

Comment: There's no language "C++11/14". Pick one.

Comment: @KerrekSB The OP never claimed that, and even made it clear (see the links behind 11 and 14) that this question applies to both. Would you please stop nitpicking?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yeah, this is not something you'd normally guess.

```
virtual auto what() const noexcept -> const char * override;
```

This is just the order you have to use. The syntax could have been different, probably, but this is what we've got.

Comment: Ugh. And why does anyone think this is superior? It is certainly not more readable. This notation should be used only in limited cases like for templates where it is really necessary.

Comment: Why should the syntax have been different? The new syntax delays the *return type*, not qualifiers or other things... "virtual", "const", "override" and "noexcept" are not part of the return type so they stay where they were.

Comment: @CodyGray Nobody would say that the new syntax is cleaner here. I would advise to not use it in this case. It was introduced for generic code where you need to have the type function parameters in scope to form the return type. It is not an aesthetic reason. Ah, and for lambdas, of course...

Comment: Coming from Swift (with "throws" instead of the negative "noexcept"), the syntax seems quite natural to me. I see it like this: an exception/error occurs before the mapping (the arrow) succeeds. Maybe because "noexcept" is a negative term and we humans aren't good with negation?

Comment: @RandyMarsh That doesn't make sense to me, and it's not because `noexcept` being a negative term, it's because it doesn't make any difference which gets parsed first. At compile time, both are needed to continue the compilation process, and either order would work. And at run time, it's not a matter of which comes first either: an exception may be thrown, a value may be returned, but never both. Maybe Swift works differently, in which case I simply do not understand what you mean.

Comment: @hvd Swift errors are similar to exceptions in semantics: either an error is thrown or a value is returned. The difference is that Swift requires opting in with "throws" while C++ allows opting out from exceptions. "throws" must be put exactly before the arrow; I didn't know "noexcept" was like a storage class in C++.

Comment: @RandyMarsh It's not like a storage class, but the fact that you put that in your comment made me wonder why you would think that, and gave me a vague sense of some possible fundamental differences between Swift and C++. I think someone needs to be be skilled in both languages to explain properly, and sorry, I've never worked with Swift. But perhaps to others that do use it, your comment will be useful :)

Answer (score 37):

The reason for the problem is that `noexcept` is part of the function declarator (and proposed to be part of the function type in C++17), while `override` is an (optionally used) identifier that is not part of the function declarator.

Hence, without use of `override` the declaration would be

```
virtual auto what() const noexcept -> const char *;
```

and, since `override` must appear after this declaration, it will result in

```
virtual auto what() const noexcept -> const char * override;
```

That said, rather than slavishly using C++11/C++14 features, pick the ones which best reflect your intent.    There is not some rule that requires only use of C++11/C++14 features if there are older alternatives to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 21):

The new syntax supports everything the old syntax does.

```
virtual const char* what() const noexcept override;
```

must be rewritten as

```
virtual auto what() const noexcept -> const char * override;
```

---

Actually, the new syntax supports even more features:

- It allows you to do `decltype` on function arguments.

  ```
  template <typename A, typename B> auto plus(A a, B b) -> decltype(a+b)
  {
      return A + B;
  }
  ```
- It also allows you to do `decltype` on `this`, which in turn allows you to do `decltype` on member functions. [See this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038832/inside-of-a-class-why-auto-b-decltypea-works-but-decltypea)

  ```
  struct S
  {
      int a() {return 1;}
      auto b() -> decltype(a()) {return 2;} // Works.
      decltype(a()) c() {return 2;} // ERROR.
  };
  ```

---

But while the new syntax has all those additional features, **it's not supposed to be a replacement for the old one.** At least this is how I understand it.

Some programmers prefer to use it, but as far as I know most programmers here on Stack Overflow prefer to use the old syntax when possible.

Comment: And in particular trailing return type allows you to use a type defined in the class, unqualified in the return type.

Answer (score 1):

Since you inquired about C++14 too, for your scenario, this is better than the suffix return type syntax;

```
virtual auto what() const noexcept override;
```

Comment: ... in those circumstances where you're allowed to omit the return type altogether (i.e. it can be illegal when you have multiple `return` statements, for example)