# Meaning of "const -> std::string const&" after the function definition?

Tags: c++, c++14

Reading the answer for one exercise in *C++ Primer, 5th Edition*, I found this code:

```
#ifndef CP5_ex7_04_h
#define CP5_ex7_04_h
#include <string>

class Person {
std::string name;
std::string address;
public:

auto get_name() const -> std::string const& { return name; }
auto get_addr() const -> std::string const& { return address; }
};

#endif
```

What does

```
const -> std::string const&
```

mean in this case?

Comment: **Trailing return type** syntax. Basically, `auto func() -> type` = `type func()`, but the first one has more features. In your case it has no advantages and was probably used because someone who wrote the code likes it more than the normal syntax.

Comment: Means it is a **get only** property.

Comment: @FirstStep: C++ doesn't have "properties".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: you says first one has more features ? What features it provides ?

Comment: Well yeah @LightnessRacesinOrbit. It is a Get-Only method ^^ TankS yew vary mush 4 ... it out.

Comment: @Destructor in templated code it allows return types which depends on deduced template types.

Comment: @Destructor See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38541155/is-the-new-c-return-syntax-limited/38541357#38541357

Comment: @FirstStep: C++ doesn't have "methods".

Answer (score 21):

`auto get_name() const -> std::string const& { return name; }` is *trailing return type* notation for the equivalent

`std::string const& get_name() const { return name; }`

Note that the equivalence is *exact* in the sense that you can *declare* a function using one syntax and *define* it with the other.

(This has been part of the C++ standard since and including C++11).

Comment: In which version of C++ was this introduced? I've never seen it before.

Comment: @MarkRansom: C++11. You use it whenever you write a lambda (though you probably omit the trailing return type in practice a lot of the time). You'll also see the monstrosity that is `auto main() -> int {}` wherever Alf writes a C++ answer on SO ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I made the comment in the hopes that it would be added to the answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know, but 1) I honestly didn't know until you told me, and 2) I don't like editing other people's answers, it seems kind of rude. P.S. 3) it's always good to get people to think about leaving better answers.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit: the term *declaration* was not entirely correct.

Comment: @MarkRansom: You could have just said "thanks for the info" :P

Comment: @Bathsheba: How so? A definition is also a declaration.

Comment: Methinks it was unhelpful to refer to my first block of code as a declaration.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: why can't return type of `main()` be automatically deduced ? Why `auto main()` is not allowed ?

Comment: Was this declaration style created for functions which are not allowed to modify class objects ? (otherwise a std::string const& get_name(); would suffice )

Comment: @user: No, the C++03 syntax already permits `std::string const& get_name() const;`  The purpose of the new syntax is to have more names in lexical scope while the return type is processed, which is handy when using `decltype`.

Comment: @Destructor: In C++11, [the feature doesn't exist for functions](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c26fe845cc95923). In C++14, [it doesn't seem to want to work with `main`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/354a1c63ec37a406), and off the top of my head I'm not sure why that is (I'd be tempted to say it's actually a compiler bug, but neither brand new clang nor brand new GCC are happy with it; [I have asked SO for advice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39106798/560648)). Obviously if you omitted `return 0` like a good boy then it would all be moot anyway ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : [basic.start.main]/2: "It shall have a _declared_ return type of type `int`"

Comment: @Destructor: There; per the linked SO question, the wording is indeed there in C++14 (I was using an old draft). So the answer for C++14 is, "because the committee says so". :)

Answer (score 9):

The part `-> std::string const&` is trailing return type and is new syntax since C++11.

The first `const` says it a `const` member function. It can be safely called on a `const` object of type `Person`.

The second part simply tells what the return type is - `std:string const&`.

It is useful when the return type needs to be deduced from a template argument. For known return types, it is no more useful than than using:

```
std::string const& get_name() const { return name; }
```

Answer (score 4):

It all makes more sense when you see an example where it actually matters; as written in the question, it's just an alternative way to declare the return type.

If you have a template function where you can not know the return type in advance, this can actually help. For example:

```
template <class X, class Y> auto DoSomeThing(X x, Y y) -> decltype(x * y);
```

You don't know what types `X` and `Y` actually are but you know the return value will have the same type as `x * y` which can be deduced in this way.

Answer (score 3):

`const` is a [cv-qualifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions) of the usual kind for the member function : `*this` is `const` inside the function.

`-> std::string const&` pairs with `auto` to form a [trailing return type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) (see (2)). The difference is only syntactic here -- the following syntax is equivalent:

```
std::string const& get_name() const { return name; }
```