# Why can the return type of main not be deduced?

Tags: c++, c++14, return-type-deduction

As expected, the following fails in C++11 because that language does not have return type deduction for bog standard functions:

```
auto main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

However, C++14 does, so I cannot explain the following error (with equivalent outcomes in GCC trunk, clang 3.8 and Visual Studio 2015):

```
error: 'main' must return 'int'
```

Is there a passage in the standard that I'm not seeing, forbidding return type deduction for `main`? Or are both compilers non-compliant?

*(For what it's worth, I'd never actually do this. `int main()` for the win…)*

Comment: I was able to reproduce this in Visual Studio as well.

Comment: @Xirema: Thanks! 2015, I assume?

Comment: Looking at cppreference (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function): "7) (since C++14) The return type of the main function cannot be deduced (auto main() {... is not allowed)"

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17135093/3545094

Comment: What if there are multiple `return` statements in the main function returning different types (int, double etc) of data?

Comment: @MuhammadAli, that's actually a good point which I originally wanted to mention in my answer. However that anyways fails for normal functions as well. So `main()` can be a no exception in that. BTW, this question seems like an exact duplicate of [Will automatic return type deduction work for main?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17134975/514235) and not just related.

Comment: @iammilind: I won't fight the duplicate but it's hardly "exact". For starters, run a diff: you'll find lots of characters differ. Speaking more broadly, that one asks whether return type for `main` "will be" deduced in C++14... while this one, starting with the premise that answer should be "yes", asks why various compilers are giving results that contrast with that answer. Do they have a bug, or is there something else at play? Unfortunately, the premise was flawed because I was using an outdated draft by mistake, so it's all kind of moot.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Reading [the C++17 draft](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4594.pdf) §3.6.1/2:

> ... and it shall have a declared return type of type `int`, ...

So yes I would say it's forbidden to use deduction.

---

Almost the exact same wording in [the last C++14 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (same section as the C++17 draft):

> It shall have a declared return type of type `int`, ...

---

Just a personal reflection on the *possible* reasoning behind this, after reading comments and other answers. The reasoning return-type deduction is not allowed is (I think) because then the return type isn't known by the compiler until it sees a `return` statement. It's also not uncommon that other types (that are implicitly convertible to `int`) might be returned which would make the deduced type wrong. Declaring the return type up-front (either by the normal old-fashioned way, or by using trailing return type) will set the type when the function is declared, and can be checked by the compiler then and there to be correct.

As for allowing type-aliases, they are just aliases of a type. So allowing e.g.

```
typedef int my_type;
my_type main() { ... }
```

is really no different from

```
int main() { ... }
```

Comment: So in this code the declared return type is `MyType`, not `int`: `typedef int MyInt; MyInt main() { }`, but clang and gcc accept. Any reason?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i agree that the type `MyInt` *is* the type `int`. But I declared main with `MyInt`, not with `int`. I can also see how your `auto` gets changed to a type that *is* the type `int` after the return statement. So then `main`'s return type *is* the type `int` aswell in your and my code. But yours is rejected, and mine not. I don't understand.

Comment: I think my code is invalid aswell because I did not give `main` a declared return type of `int`. Can you please explain?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: You did! It's just spelt differently. In the `auto` case you didn't provide a type at all. So I guess that's the difference.

Comment: N4296 is not the "last C++14 draft". It's the first C++17 draft with fold expressions and all that. The C++14 DIS is N3937 (N3936 has the same content but a different cover page); the IS is N4141 (N4140 is the IS + editorial fixes).

Comment: @T.C. That's not what the [isocpp.org website says](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard): "This working draft contains the C++14 standard plus minor editorial changes."

Comment: @T.C. Gasp. Who should we flog for this? A lot of people refer to N4296 as "C++14".

Comment: @isanae: I Googled N4296 and it sent me to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29115882/560648)... funnily enough written by T.C. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is actually pretty major, I've always relied on N4296. Does anybody here have any contacts with the people who manage isocpp.org? The first hit for "c++14 draft" on google is N3797 and the second is isocpp.org, which has N4296.

Comment: If anyone has tweeter they could send to @isocpp letting them know about the mistake

Comment: @isanae: Indeed; as it happens, that's precisely how this question came about!

Comment: As to the rationale, [this comment from Richard Smith](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134975/will-automatic-return-type-deduction-work-for-main#comment26296723_17135093) is relevant.

Answer (score 17):

From 3.6.1/2 (emphasis mine):

> [...]it shall have a **declared return type** of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.

When `auto` is used without a trailing return type, the *declared return type* of a function is still `auto`, even though the *deduced return type* can be something else. The difference between *declared* and *deduced* isn't spelled out plainly in the standard, but 7.1.6.4/7 may shed some light:

> When [...] a `return` statement occurs in a function declared with a return type that contains a placeholder type, the deduced return type [...] is determined from the type of its initializer. In the case of a `return` with no operand or with an operand of type `void`, the declared return type shall be `auto` and the deduced return type is `void`.

My understanding is that with this:

```
auto main(){ return 0; }
```

the *declared return type* would still be `auto`, although the *deduced return type* would be `int`. As per 3.6.1/2 above, the *declared return type* of `main` **must** be `int`. Therefore, this is ill-formed.

However, a trailing return type is considered a *declared return type*. From 7.1.6.4/2:

> If the function declarator includes a *trailing-return-type* (8.3.5), that *trailing-return-type* specifies the declared return type of the function.

```
$ cat a.cpp
auto main() -> int {}
$ g++ -Wall -std=c++14 a.cpp
$
```

<sup>All quotes are identical in both C++14 and C++17.</sup>

Comment: The real question is why an inferred type from a return statement does not specify the declared return type of the function.

Comment: @Random832 I've updated my answer, although there's no real answer as to _why_.

Answer (score 8):

From 3.6.1 [basic.start.main]

> 1 A program shall contain a global function called main, which is the
>   designated start of the program.... 
> 2 An implementation shall not
>   predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. It
>   shall have a declared return type of type int, but otherwise its type
>   is implementation-defined...

If the standard were to restrict deduction, then I think the verbiage "declared return type int" would be it.

Comment: This is the wording for C++14 as of N4296 (the draft I have on hand)

Comment: Ah, you're right - my draft is too old. I thought it was the FDIS. :(

Answer (score 4):

Many answers have nicely mention the quotes from the standard. But there is another subtle problem with `auto` as return type.

According to C++ standard ([somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)), the **`return` statement is not mandatory** inside `main()`. This is explicitly mentioned in Bjarne Stroustrup's [website](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main):

> In C++, `main()` need not contain an explicit `return` statement. In that case, the value returned is `0`, meaning successful execution.

Which means below statement is valid:

```
auto main () {}
```

One can assume an implicit `return 0;` statement just before `}`. So in such case `auto` is *interpreted as* `int`. However, from technicality of C++14, the `auto` must be *deduced to* `void` because of no return statement! So, "`int` vs `void`", what to consider?

IMO this is the caveat, which prevents `auto` as a return type in a logical sense as well.

Comment: _"Which means below statement is valid"_ I don't follow your reasoning. Obviously you cannot use return type deduction without a return statement. That in no way means that it shouldn't be able to use return type deduction when you _do_ write a return statement, just as with any other function.

Comment: @Light, you wrote: *"Obviously you cannot use return type deduction without a return statement"*. It's not true. Ofcourse we can deduce `return` type without `return` statement! [Demo](http://ideone.com/CBtnkF). When there is no return type, it's deduced as `void` as seen there. Your remaining sentence is unclear. Anyhow, you can try to follow the linked dupe, if it helps.

Comment: (except when you want to deduce `void`)* The remaining sentence is quite clear but without knowing what part of it you're confused about, I cannot help.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in various comments, I was indeed missing it in the standard, because what I thought was a copy of the C++14 FDIS was in fact no such thing (but, instead, a marginally older draft), and the word "declared" was snuck into the relevant passage after [CWG 1669](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1669).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13436063)

Comment: @miken32: It most certainly is an answer, and I'm unlikely to request clarification from myself.

Comment: Nice find on 1669.

Comment: @isanae: Can't really take credit for that ;) Amadeus linked me to a cppreference.com page I missed, then I scoured the revision history and saw a link to 1669 in the comment for the commit that introduced the relevant text.

Comment: It's also mentioned on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134975/will-automatic-return-type-deduction-work-for-main/17135093#17135093). If I were brave enough, I'd flag this question as a duplicate :)

Comment: This is not an answer as mentioned by @miken32. Also the original question was reopened even though it's a duplicate of [Will automatic return type deduction work for main?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134975/will-automatic-return-type-deduction-work-for-main). "Efficient" use of gold badge!

Comment: @iammilind: Yes, it certainly _is_ an answer, as discussed almost a month ago. Did you have anything useful or constructive to add, at all?